# Как отформатировать диск COSMOS

Tags: c#

Скажите пожалуйста, как я могу отформатировать созданный диск в COSMOS? Смотрел в документации, там написано:

`fs.Format("0" /*drive id*/, "FAT32" /*fat type*/, true /*use quick format*/);`

Но на практике, выходит следующая ошибка:

> *Ошибка    CS1061  "CosmosVFS" не содержит определения "Format", и не удалось найти доступный метод расширения "Format", принимающий тип "CosmosVFS" в качестве первого аргумента (возможно, пропущена директива using или ссылка на сборку).*

Как отформатировать диск? `using System.IO` подключено.

Comment: Есть такой тест, может поможет https://github.com/CosmosOS/Cosmos/blob/master/Tests/Cosmos.System.Tests/DiskManagerTest.cs

Comment: Спасибо, помогло!

Comment: Вы можете оформить правильное решение как ответ, показать код. Это может кому-то пригодиться.

Answer (score 1):

Всё просто. У класса FS нет функции Format, но она есть у класса Disk. Дабы получить список дисков, используется функция fs.GetDisks(), затем выбираешь нужный диск (это список) и производишь форматирование раздела через функцию FormatPartition.